# Should I enable OAuth for Youtube APi if I wont use it?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Without OAuth after request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={API_KEY}&channelId={chanel_ID}&part=snippet&maxResults=20
```

I getting message "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project". But it is enabled. Should I add OAuth credentials even if I wont use it, or it problem have another reasons?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was working and suddenly stopped. Im not using OAuth.

So I created a New Project with a new Credential and setup the new credential.

Its working again... But I dont know if it will suddenly stop.